# Background in storyboard show segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I am facing a really weird problem with a storyboard segue.
As you can see from the GIF, I don't know how to solve this background color glitch in the segue. I made the segue in the inspector. Other segues are working fine.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showTask") {
        let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let destinationVC = nav.topViewController as! ShowTaskVC
        destinationVC.singleTask = self.selectedTask
    }
    else if (segue.identifier == "showSettings") {
        let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let destinationVC = nav.topViewController as! SettingsVC
        destinationVC.orderBy = self.orderBy
    }
    else if (segue.identifier == "addNewTask") {
        let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let _ = nav.topViewController as! AddTaskVC
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me why is this happening? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: it seems you have set parent color as clearColor

Comment: parent color of what? Can you give me more details please?

Comment: that presenting controller : make sure any view color should not clear in view hierarchy.

Comment: background color of view controller is grey as presented

Comment: can show code of how you are presenting next vc

Comment: Change your presentation option to default

Comment: I added more code